# Screen black if nomodeset is not enabled

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS 8100 with an i7 870 and a GTX 460. It used to run Windows 10 (which worked fine), but recently I decided to try installing a Linux distribution on it.

Initially I decided to go with Ubuntu. It gave me no video unless I ran it with `nomodeset`, but even after that I had issues getting it installed due to the RAID configuration the computer uses, so I decided to try Fedora instead.

Fedora had the same issue, had to enable `nomodeset`, but after that it installed fine. Once in the installed Fedora, however, `nomodeset` remained, and I decided to try installing the proprietary NVIDIA driver (`akmod-nvidia` from RPM Fusion) to see if that would help. Unfortunately it did not, as while that did make it boot without `nomodset`, it instead resulted in a black screen on login. Same occurs if I use the nouveau driver.

Any ideas on what I can do to get video without `nomodeset`?

Update: I installed the `akmod-nvidia-390xx` package as per recommendation, and while that does get me further (video does not stop and I get a cursor, sometimes it gets to the display manager), rarely do I get all the way to the desktop (I was only able to do so for a few seconds in OpenBox).

Comment: https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/

Comment: It would have been much easier if you kept Ubuntu, where you can install the drivers with Software & Updates > Additional Drivers, selecting and applying the recommended version, entirely in a GUI tool.

Comment: Its unclear what you are tryibg to do and why. In order to get rid of nomodeset you would need to get a video card that does not reqyire it or make kernel changes (ie write code) to do something equivalent to that or ensure the system boots to X and live with a black screen until it boots.

Comment: @davidgo I'm trying to make use of my GTX 460, which I hope is possible somehow.

Comment: I.dont understand what using a GTX460 has to do with not using nomodeset. Install your distro, install the proprietary drivers (which drive Xwindows) and use nomodeset to boot to Xwindows.

Comment: @davidgo it has to do with not using nomodeset because using nomodeset is the only way I so far have been able to get a working desktop with this card.

Comment: @Newbyte what they're trying to ask is what is the problem with using nomodeset? It is the only way, so why not leave it that way?

Comment: @Fanatique aha. My issue with nomodeset is the lack of 3D acceleration and that things don't look very pretty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much of a solution, but I believe I have found the issue.

I attempted to give Windows 10 another shot today, and lo and behold, it boot-looped immediately after the installation was finished. With this in mind, I think it's safe to write this one off as a hardware failure.

Answer (score 0):

Not a hardware failure. I have the same issue as you with two systems...both using GTX 460 cards. It appears something has changed in both the Linux kernel and the current build of Windows 10. Neither like the old GTX 460 Fermi anymore.

Solution? I am sticking with Windows 7 and Linux Mint 17 on these boxes. I can't recall what kernel Mint 17 is using off of the top of my head, but it is the LAST version that booted into the GUI properly with the GTX 460...at least for me. All versions after 17 go to black screen even on the live usb.